# Control Limit for number of Logged in Users in MVC Web App

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

I want to set the limit to control the number of users logged in at same time.

**Scenario:-**

I have one MVC web application, `Customer A` will buy my app with XYZ amount. I will allow 3 user at a same time can logged into that App. Now `Customer A` again comes to me and say I want to increase number of user limit to 10. I will say OK pay this much amount I will do that.

Now I want to set user logged in user (at same time)limit to 10.

My Question is How can I achieve this concept in MVC.

**What I Tried:-**

I used `Application` variable to achieve this but there are some scenario like user logged in but without logout he/she closed browser at that time how I can i decrees current logged in user count.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force logout and you can not tell when the browser has closed.

I have two suggestions for you

**Client to server:**
If you expect a relatively low concurrent user count i would have a global Jquery Function which polls the server ever x seconds.

A user logins, you store their "token", "IP" and "last action time" and give them the "token" (token should be unique).
Every x seconds, have a jquery function call the server with the token and update the "last action time"

On login, test if the user has 10 logins which are currently active. If yes, refuse. (last action with in x seconds)

- Issue here is false positives where a user could actually be logged off but x are with in X.

**Server to Client**
Use signalr or other tech to poll users who are logged in to see if they are still logged in.